# sqrtf(6)*sqrtf(6) != 6 in xcode

Tags: objective-c, macos, xcode4, sqrt

I'm trying to create a software that shows the angle between two vectors and it's not working when then are equal to (1,1,2), hence the modulus of this vector is sqrtf(6) which is rouding to 2.449490 and it should be 2.44948974278318.

Is there a way to increase precision of this operation?

In the next steps of my software I make this operation:

```
float angle = acos(dot/(modulus1*modulus2));
```

If modulus1 == modulus 2, then modulus1*modulus2 = dot, but it's not happening with some values.

I hope I made myself clear.

Thanks in advance,
Gruber

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know about Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Article above elaborates, but watch out for roundoff errors.

Comment: Use double (64) or decimal (80/128)?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `double` if you want greater precision. However, note that the `==` operation on floating point numbers never work the way they do with integral types. Use an epsilon to adjust for minor differences.

Comment: The `==` operation works exactly the same for float and integral types; it returns true if and only if the values are equal.  The difference is that a programmer's intuition of the actual *values* involved is often mistaken, because most never bother to really understand floating point.

Comment: @StephenCanon: That is what I meant. But I guess I'd add that minor but *important* clarification.

Comment: The main problem here is that is 2.4494897 and Xcode keeps showing me 2.449490... I tried all data types and it didn't work either.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @EltonGruber: Do you mean that the debugger is showing you `2.449490`? That could be a bug. Try good ol' `printf`-ing the exact values (and use a high enough precision specifier). Now, as I said earlier, you will probably need to use some epsilon to account for the fact that floating point representation is not exact.

Comment: @dirkgently thanks for answering so quickly... I was trying to use NSLog(@"%Lf",var).

Comment: IIRC, the default width is 6. Try with `NSLog(@"[%.14Lf]", var);`

Comment: Thank you, it's still showing the same final result though. I believe it has something to do with acos function I'm using. =)

Comment: @EltonGruber: Try: `NSLog(@"%@", [NSNumber numberWithDouble:modulus]);
` -- this should print the number with full-precision (which is ~16 decimal digits). `acos` should return a `double`. Check the width of your `double` data type with something like `NSLog(@"sizeof double: %ld", sizeof(double));`

Comment: Thank you, I converted the variable type before using acos and it's working properly now.